# can't call methods from my class.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, button, methods

i was need to write 2 methods in my student class which do the following

hasPassed() Should return True if the student has a year mark >= 40 or
false if the marks is <40

toString() Should return a single string containing a summary of the
student details held within the class
e.g.
“12345 Basil Fawlty, 23/08/1946”

here's the code i have for the above to methods, is what i have correct for what its asking for the above?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CourseWork
{
    public class Student
    {
        private static string firstname;
        private string secondname;
        private string dateofbirth;
        private string course;
        private int matricnumber;
        private double yearmark;

      public bool hasPassed()
        {
            if (yearmark >= 40)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

      public void toString()
      {
          firstname = "Basil";
          secondname = "Fawlty";
          dateofbirth = "23/08/1946";
          course = "MA Hotel Management";
          matricnumber = 12345;
          yearmark = 55;
      }

        public Student()
        {
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstname; }
            set { firstname = value; }
        }

        public string SecondName
        {
            get { return secondname; }
            set { secondname = value; }
        }
        public string DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return dateofbirth; }
            set { dateofbirth = value; }
        }

        public string Course
        {
            get { return course; }
            set { course = value; }
        }
        public int MatricNumber
        {
            get { return matricnumber; }
            set
            {
                if (value <= 99999 && value >= 10000)
                {
                    matricnumber = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Matric Number: {0}", value);
                }

              matricnumber = value;
            }
        }
        public double YearMark
        {
            set
            {
                if (value <= 100 && value >= 0)
                {
                    yearmark = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Year Mark: {0}", value);
                }
              yearmark = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

i then need the above methods to be used in a get button that does the following

Get: Uses the values of the Student class methods to update the text boxes. The
Student.hasPassed() method should be used to update the pass/fail label. The
Student details summary should be updated by using Student.toString ().

but I'm having trouble coding it and i cant seam to call hasPassed() method or toString() method from my student class

so I've doing something wrong but cant see what it is
any ideas how to go about fixing this?

Comment: what is the trouble?are you getting exceptions?

Comment: You did create an instance of Student class, right? (Ex.: Student john = new Student()) Can we see the code that call and managed the student?

Comment: Can you post your calling code? Also, do you want to override the `ToString` method, or is that a method name you made up?

Comment: ok updated with what code i have for my student class, 

i have a set buttong that basicly let me save update vaules in the student class, though i dont think thats saving them correcty, but wont know until i get the Get button working

i have used Student student = new student() in the set button

in the get button i need to use the toString method to show the eg 12345 Basil Fawlty, 23/08/194  in the txt boxes and in a label, i then need to use hasPassed() method in the Get button so that when a yearmark is >= 40 another label says Pass or fail if < 40

Answer (score 2):

In order the methods to be visible, you need to create an instance of the class `Student`. ex,

```
Student _student = new Student();
bool _x = _student.hasPassed();
```

if you want the members to be access without instantiating, make the member static,

```
  public static bool hasPassed()
  {
        if (yearmark >= 40)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
  }
```

but bear in mind that static members cannot see non-static members. In that case, it won;t compile because `yearmark` cannot be found.